# What is the best way to fix this X11 forwarding related issue in Java application?

Tags: java, swing, x11-forwarding

Sometimes, mostly for testing, I use X11 forwarding when I run a remote Java Swing application. I use the SSH's `C` (compression) and `Y` (forwarding) options.

My _JAVA_OPTIONS has the following value: `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false`

When I run the remote application I am getting the following:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -18350080  Thread: AWT-EventQu                                                                        eue-0
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sun.font.FileFontStrike.getCachedGlyphPtr(FileFontStrike.java:472)
sun.font.FileFontStrike.getSlot0GlyphImagePtrs(FileFontStrike.java:438)
sun.font.CompositeStrike.getGlyphImagePtrs(CompositeStrike.java:115)
sun.font.GlyphList.mapChars(GlyphList.java:272)
sun.font.GlyphList.setFromString(GlyphList.java:244)
sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawString(GlyphListPipe.java:71)
sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(SunGraphics2D.java:2867)
sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.drawString(SwingUtilities2.java:563)
sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(SwingUtilities2.java:584)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.paintEnabledText(BasicLabelUI.java:119)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.paint(BasicLabelUI.java:179)
javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:769)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)
javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.paintCurrentValue(BasicComboBoxUI.java:12                                                                        55)
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI.paintCurrentValue(MetalComboBoxUI.java:90                                                                        )
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.paint(BasicComboBoxUI.java:903)
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI.paint(MetalComboBoxUI.java:62)
javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:769)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paintChildren(BackgroundPanel.java:147)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paint(BackgroundPanel.java:104)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paintChildren(BackgroundPanel.java:147)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paint(BackgroundPanel.java:104)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paintChildren(BackgroundPanel.java:147)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paint(BackgroundPanel.java:104)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paintChildren(BackgroundPanel.java:147)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paint(BackgroundPanel.java:104)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paintChildren(BackgroundPanel.java:147)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paint(BackgroundPanel.java:104)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paintChildren(BackgroundPanel.java:147)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
bibliothek.gui.dock.util.BackgroundPanel.paint(BackgroundPanel.java:104)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295                                                                        )
javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:7                                                                        6)
javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:7                                                                        6)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242                                                                        )
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:870)
com.areen.jlib.util.ExceptionLogger.uncaughtException(ExceptionLogger.java:64)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(EventDispatchThread.java:264)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:256                                                                        )
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:870)
com.areen.jlib.util.ExceptionLogger.uncaughtException(ExceptionLogger.java:64)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(EventDispatchThread.java:264)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:256                                                                        )
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150                                                                        )
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Could be that I hit a bug: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7180898 ... Not 100% sure.

Comment: Could you supply the exact, full command that you're running?  Also, what flavor and version of Unix/Linux are you running from, as well as the client you're SSH-ing to?

Comment: Is there a font available on the client that is _not_ on the local X server to which the client is forwarded?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland - I will check, but considering that I am using some themes, and few different L&F, it is very much possible that this causes problem(s)... Thanks!

Comment: If that's it, you might try substituting a [_logical font_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).